# How can I cast custom type to primitive type?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, casting

I have a type

```
type Rating = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | number
```

Now I want to do something like this.

```
let myRating:Rating = 4
let rate:number = myRating as number
```

How can I cast my `myRating` into `number` primitive type?

It is giving me error as:

> Conversion of type 'Rating' to type 'number' may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other. If this was intentional, convert the expression to 'unknown' first.ts(2352)

I have been through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type), but what I want is its reverse

Edit:

> tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es6",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "strict": true
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

tsc version: 3.2.1

Comment: Which typescript version are you using? Also, share your tsconfig file, because your code compiles for me with no errors using `typescript@3.2.2`

Comment: @NitzanTomer I've updated my question

Comment: Excuse me, but if you include the type `number` in your type `Rating`, why even bother putting the list of numbers 0-5?

Comment: I added number later to make it work. It is not working in either case

Comment: It worked, it is because of the name conflict between library Rating and my type name Rating, I renamed my type as RatingType and it worked.

Comment: I can't reproduce this, using your tsconfig it compiles just fine.

Answer (score 213, accepted):

You cannot cast from a *custom* to a *primitive* without *erasing* the type first. `unknown` erases the type checking.

Try :

```ts
myRating as unknown as number
```

Or :

```ts
myRating as any
```

Also, remove `| number` from your declaration.

Comment: I ran into this recently when trying covariance. This solution just doesn't seem right. But it works.

Comment: You can't cast from a custom to a primitive without 'erasing' the type first.  `unknown` erases the type checking.

Answer (score 11):

## Update 2020

TS 3.8 update

now no need to cast using as, it is supported implicitly except in some cases. Where you can do type conversion as given in the accepted answer. Here is a good explanation of [type conversion on the typescript](https://garbagevalue.com/blog/typescript-custom-to-primitive-type-casting).

```
type Rating = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;
let myRating:Rating = 4
let rate:number = myRating;
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=3&ssc=1&pln=3&pc=28#code/C4TwDgpgBASghsAlgOwOZQLxQAxQD5QCM%20UATCQMwkAsJArANwBQANhMFALYjxJoBcvFOizVW7KACcEEfsgCunAEYRJmLjwTCGQA)

---

## Original Answer

I think it is fixed in the typescript update TS 3.5.1

```
type Rating = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;
let myRating:Rating = 4
```

Now

```
let rate:number = myRating;
```

and

```
let rate:number = myRating as number;
```

both working fine.

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBASghsAlgOwOZQLxQAxQD5QCM+UATCQMwkAsJArANwBQANhMFALYjxJoBcvFOizVW7KACcEEfsgCunAEYRJmLjwTCocAM5QFy1QyA)