# How do I validate an environment variable string against an inline union type e.g. <16 | 32 | 64>?

Tags: typescript

I'm working with the `rpi-led-matrix` repo to successfully control an LED panel. While it has been super helpful in getting hardware controlled via TypeScript, I'm struggling a bit with its multiple inline union types when attempting to validate my own unknown/string environment variables.

This example works so far when setting the number of LED panel rows option. No validation yet:

config.ts

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { LedMatrix, MatrixOptions } from 'rpi-led-matrix'

dotenv.config({ path: `${__dirname}/.env` })

export const matrixOptions: MatrixOptions = {
  ...LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions(),
  rows: process.env.MATRIX_ROWS
    ? <16 | 32 | 64>Number(process.env.MATRIX_ROWS)
    : LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions().rows,
}
```

To better handle validation and communicate any issues in console, I'm trying to break this out into a utils file:

configUtils.ts

```
const matrixRowOptions = [16, 32, 64]
type MatrixRowOptions = typeof matrixRowOptions[number]

export const configMatrixRows = (
  configRows?: string | number,
): MatrixRowOptions => {
  const rows = Number(configRows) as MatrixRowOptions
  if (matrixRowOptions.includes(rows)) {
    return rows
  }

  if (rows) {
    console.error(
      `supplied rows value of ${rows} is not a valid option, assigning default of ${
        LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions().rows
      }.`,
    )
  }

  return LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions().rows
}
```

new config.ts:

```
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'
import { LedMatrix, MatrixOptions } from 'rpi-led-matrix'
import { configMatrixRows } from './configUtils';

dotenv.config({ path: `${__dirname}/.env` })

export const matrixOptions: MatrixOptions = {
  ...LedMatrix.defaultMatrixOptions(),
  rows: configMatrixRows(process.env.MATRIX_ROWS), // <<<  not happy
}
```

TypeScript Error:

```
Type 'number' is not assignable to type '16 | 32 | 64'.ts(2322)
types.d.ts(207, 5): The expected type comes from property 'rows' which is declared here on type 'MatrixOptions'
```

I'm missing something. How do I resolve the error and successfully validate unknown data for the inline union type? I've pulled initial inspiration from this [Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53813384/1279000), however it's not quite hitting the mark yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happening because the type `MatrixRowOptions` is just `number`. This makes the return type of `configMatrixRows` just `number` as well, which will lead to the error since `number` is wider than `16 | 32 | 64`.

So why is the type of `MatrixRowOptions` `number`?

Because the type of the variable `matrixRowOptions` is also just `number[]`. So `typeof matrixRowOptions[number]` will resolve to `number`.

You have to convert `matrixRowOptions` to a tuple with the three elements `16`, `32` and `64`. For that we use `as const`.

```
const matrixRowOptions = [16, 32, 64] as const
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.7.2#code/LAKAlgtgDg9gTgFwAQCokEMDOSAmMECmAdgG5IBmcMESA5HoabaJLIkgN5IAyBOAsugRwwADwA0SQcLEB5KAjAwi2AL4UqNWnChgAtABs%20eiEJGjmIUAGNlmZFCrWCmTAC5OSYiQ8AlArZwOAA89iJEAOaSYWCRAHxI6gC8nKBIXqQeHKqgOVYgtirIpjKivjAA7vKKdkgpANoAjABskgDMAEySzQAsALoY2IX2oAgAnlAEUmZi5VUKSip1SOOTMORIJeZz1YuY9UQArhAARgRwfaCgBKJsyMP3yuRgEdLbldgpABRpSIXPETmmAA-B4YpEkAAfJBHU7ncSgACUHjes0qu1qSQSHF%20DyQVAqnyQADljmc4F9-i8gYjBtNSjsFnZfmANl8tmj5jUVAA6WLWAyHHAuL4EzCI2k4kDpdJwAgIQ5wIj4j6-PIstliyW-dLDGBGHnnKgUnUygAGmEOUCgBjAfBVhKQJHQgqm6yQABIOGL1GBsER8BgnS6wDgkDAmURJFhMC8iLEIrgCOR0IcDMh3V7TTKeHxUaIecKU2mEPmMSovoieWLs4keWaEdKZYi1Vcm3KFUrcwIZgWi6n02XI5hK9XVSB1SAGN4eVSIl8uFAhAALDxm9AnawAekNpDNiRb%20Rudz%20dmKvfL7np5kvyyl6R5j94PdKheTA9LF%20Hlcbso%20HjnfMgS%20RwYGcVxdxIHl%20AAQQAFV8ABJAANAB9XxZAAdQAZURSQty3JBgmIpBAF4NwBaPZhQNl3Qa0xlyIA)

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation. My issue is now resolved for a better day.