# TypeScript type assertions doesn't fail on incorrect value

Tags: javascript, typescript

We're using the library `msal` and are trying to convert our javaScript code to TypeScript.

The following picture indicates that TS correctly knows the type expected for `cacheLocation`. This can be either the string `localStorage`, the string `sessionStorage` or `undefined`. However, when trying to wire this together with a variable that holds one of the expected values it fails:

[image]

The issue would be fixed by using the following syntax. The only problem in this case is that a wrong value is not flagged as incorrect:

[image]

When reading the [TS docs on Type Assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) it says that this is by design and the developer knows that the type will be correct. I did however expect TS to throw an error if an unknown value would've been used.

Is there a better way for doing this? Or is this simply how it's done? Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm still learning TS.

**Code**

```js
import * as config from 'src/app-config.json'
import { Configuration, CacheLocation } from 'msal'

const test = 'wrongValue'

export function MSALConfigFactory(): Configuration {
  return {
    auth: {
      clientId: config.auth.clientId,
      authority: config.auth.authority,
      validateAuthority: true,
      redirectUri: config.auth.redirectUri,
      postLogoutRedirectUri: config.auth.postLogoutRedirectUri,
      navigateToLoginRequestUrl: true,
    },
    cache: {
      cacheLocation: test as CacheLocation,
      storeAuthStateInCookie: false,
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you post code, not pictures please. In this case one line of code is worth a thousand pictures :)

Comment: Sure thing, code added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a typo: in your first image you have LocalStora**n**ge (note the extra n)

[image]

Comment: You are correct, in the example I use a simple string but in my real app I'm reading a `.json` file that contains the value `localStorage` in `config.cache.cacheLocation` and then it fails.

Comment: When the data is not hard-coded, but comes from an external source, typescript cannot validate it - typescript can only check types that are known at compile time. So in your case, you must write some custom code to validate your external data and when it is okay, you can cast it to the desired type.

Comment: You may want to take a look at typescript validation libraries: e.g. [class-validator](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator), [joi](https://github.com/hapijs/joi), ..

Comment: The `.json` file is there at compile time. So it should find it right? It's not complaining for the other properties who are also of type `string`.

Comment: AFAIK this does not work. JSON only knows a few types: number, string, .. so whatever you import from a JSON file will just be that: number, string, ..

Comment: I think you are correct. The other values imported from the JSON file are of type string, boolean, .... not of type `localStorage`. I'm now looking at [const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type), maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

> Type '"localStorange"' is not assignable to type '"localStorage" | "sessionStorage" | undefined'
>
> *Storange*

TypeScript is very good at catching simple typos, but not so good at telling you what exactly is wrong.

Comment: You are correct, in the example I use a simple string but in my real app I'm reading a `.json` file that contains the value `localStorage` in `config.cache.cacheLocation` and then it fails.

Comment: Ah, sorry I misunderstood. @TmTron's comment is correct.