# TypeScript saying a string is invalid even though it's in the union?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I copied the following from the AWS Amplify tutorial:

```
const styles = {
  container: { flexDirection: 'column' },
  ...
};

<div style={styles.container}>
```

But I'm getting:

```
Type '{ flexDirection: string; }' is not assignable to type 'CSSProperties'.
  Types of property 'flexDirection' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"column" | "inherit" | "-moz-initial" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | "column-reverse" | "row" | "row-reverse" | undefined'.
```

I can easily work around this by placing the style inline, but I'm curious why TypeScript is considering this an error. This is a pretty basic example and I'm surprised TS is failing on it, so it makes me wary about using TS.

Comment: if it's angular then this sould be the syntax `<div [style]="styles.container">`

Comment: It's React, adding to question

Comment: the real property is `flex-direction: column` please check

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type)

Comment: @CharlesBamford no because the author in that question explicitly casted a literal to `string`. In my cast, TS is inferring the type of `styles.container.flexDirection` to be `string` rather than the literal `'column'`. I don't know why it's not treating it as a literal

Comment: try using the ```React.CSSProperties```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAYgNhAHgEQJYCcIGNioPYB2UAvFAERZ5wCuAtgWVAD7moEAWE6qwjLZAWlp4AXgLY9UAQzh9WBSTLllMANy69m5agQDOETf0o16AtV33L0eAO5XbZiOvSWtOgCYQAZmwjuA3ABQgaCQUADKoAi6JFAA3oFQSVCUBMBSvugAXPGJyfleCCgY2LiEOfBIaJg4+AR5SQC+gc2BXjq1hFDueJHUXl4AFFI5kSDRAJTxUK2pusBQ8+MQush4KwByeMAA6njoANaxCfmp6Zk5cVCFVSWdBDkA5MZ0BI8zLUGBcwtL0QCiiDAcFQWB4ABVwBBkNg4FJ0FIyg8IlEVscGilCOcCFxLtcitVSnUni96O9mo0vj9FqjdDseOwAMJSebopJnDI47LTG7FGpIklUV7vFlQZ5CskfWaEVl-FYwVAQODuRkyhakE7JDkXHkEu4CsWkt4zKCin6fYLUuW6VV6dW5U5Yzm43W3fnEw0S40U00xH5fYI9PoDQbWtabbZ7Q4TIJB4D9IbWwHA0EQqEwrBwhFImOBOMJ0O0+nAJks4C5-Mh60KpUqtUV3rxqu023zGNAA) illustrating the problem and four possible solutions:

```
type FlexDirection = "column" | "inherit" | "-moz-initial" | "initial" | "revert" | "unset" | "column-reverse" | "row" | "row-reverse" | undefined;

type Styles = {
    container: {
        flexDirection: FlexDirection
    }
}

function doStuff(a: Styles) { }

const stylesDoesNotWork = {
    container: { flexDirection: 'column' }
};

const stylesWithCast = {
  container: { flexDirection: 'column' as 'column' }
}

const stylesFieldConst = {
    container: { flexDirection: 'column' } as const
};

const stylesConst = {
    container: { flexDirection: 'column' }
} as const;

doStuff(stylesDoesNotWork);
doStuff(stylesWithCast);
doStuff(stylesFieldConst);
doStuff(stylesConst);
```

By default, TypeScript is going to infer a type `string` for the object you are declaring. You might be mutating it somewhere and changing the value, in which case the literal type would not be correct. So the basic options to fix it are to:

- Manually annotate the variable so TypeScript doesn't infer string.
- Add `as 'column'` cast to tell TypeScript to use the literal type.
- Use `as const` on either the field or entire object to tell TypeScript that field is not allowed to be changed, which allows Typescript to infer the literal value.

Comment: > You might be mutating it somewhere and changing the value, in which case the literal type would not be correct.
This makes perfect sense now, thanks!

Comment: if you are mutating it somewhere and changing the value, wouldn't it make sense for typescript to complain at the point where it is being mutated? why complain here where the value is correct and is one of the allowed values?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
const styles: { container: React.CSSProperties} = {
    container: { flexDirection: 'column' }
};
```

Comment: So `styles: { [key: string]: React.CSSProperties }` works too and it's shorter if there's lots of properties, but I don't get why I need to explicitly cast it

Answer (score 2):

import and use the type:

```
import type { Property } from 'csstype'
```

Use Property.FlexDirection to specify the type

Answer (score 2):

In my case putting `as const` on the object that was causing this problem helped to fix it.

```
// some function
return {
  label: {
    cursor: "pointer",
    display: "flex",
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "row",
  }
} as const
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me with this code :

```
let labelPosition  = {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "row",
}

<div style={labelPosition as React.CSSProperties}>
```