# Typescript why given function parameter that extends type of this parameter not allowed?

Tags: typescript

it must be an easy one but I can't figure out why typescript throws an error.

taking [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type) and tweaking at a little bit:

```
type Fruit = "Orange" | "Apple" | "Banana";
const myFruit: Fruit = "Apple";
const myString: string = myFruit;   //accepted!

// now with functions
type fruitFunc = (key: Fruit) => void;
type stringFunc = (key: string) => void;
const myFruitFunc: fruitFunc = (key: Fruit) => {};
const myStringFunc: stringFunc = myFruitFunc;   //Error!
// Type 'fruitFunc' is not assignable to type 'stringFunc'.
//   Types of parameters 'key' and 'key' are incompatible.
//     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Fruit'.ts(2322)
```

Why is that happening? I'm not trying to assign a string to fruit, but the opposite...

Answer (score 1):

Typescript tells you that `string` is not compatible with `"Orange" | "Apple" | "Banana"` which is true.

I know you tell yourself that `"Orange" | "Apple" | "Banana"` are all `strings`, so typescript should allow the function assignation but it's not how typescript works.

Typing is here to ensure that functions gets what they asked for. For example, the function `myFruitFunc` is waiting for `Fruit` as parameter, if you send a `Plant` to it, the function won't be prepared and will have unexpected behavior.

Putting the `myFruitFunc` that is waiting for Fruit inside a function pointer that would wait for a `string`, makes the use of the function unsafe.

That's why typescript is raising you an error.

---

All considered, if you still wants to store `myFruitFunc` into `myStringFunc` you can cast your function, telling typescript

> it's okay, I know what I'm doing.

```
const myStringFunc: stringFunc = myFruitFunc as stringFunc;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer - but in my code the type defenition `stringFunc` is pretty big and ugly and exist in other file(I'm writing in React -  so it's a prop of that component).
there is no other way saying to Typescript 'hey, I'm know what I'm doing,allow parameters  that extends the type of the parameters' without coping the entire type definition?