# Adding New Component Props Inside CreateTheme V5

Tags: material-ui

How can I add new props to a component inside createTheme in version 5? I see how to add new variants but not new props. Also is there a way to know what TypeScript interfaces there are to extend / augment for this purpose?

Below seems like an example of how to add a variant, however I want "hoverable" to be a prop.

Example:

```
MuiCard: {
  variants: [
    {
      props: { variant: "hoverable" },
       style: {
         "&:hover": {
           boxShadow: "0px 12px 30px rgba(37, 15, 127, 0.08)",
         },
       },
    },
 ],
}
```

TypeScript ( This doesnt seem right / work ):

```
declare module "@material-ui/core/Card" {
  interface CardPropsVariantsOverrides {
    hoverable: true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I'd do it (taken from mui.com)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { styled, createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/system';

interface MyThemeComponentProps {
  color?: 'primary' | 'secondary';
  variant?: 'normal' | 'dashed';
}

const customTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MyThemeComponent: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          color: 'darkslategray',
        },
        primary: {
          color: 'darkblue',
        },
        secondary: {
          color: 'darkred',
          backgroundColor: 'pink',
        },
      },
      variants: [
        {
          props: { variant: 'dashed', color: 'primary' },
          style: {
            border: '1px dashed darkblue',
          },
        },
        {
          props: { variant: 'dashed', color: 'secondary' },
          style: {
            border: '1px dashed darkred',
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  },
});

const MyThemeComponent = styled('div', {
  // Configure which props should be forwarded on DOM
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'color' && prop !== 'variant',
  name: 'MyThemeComponent',
  slot: 'Root',
  // We are specifying here how the styleOverrides are being applied based on props
  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => [
    styles.root,
    props.color === 'primary' && styles.primary,
    props.color === 'secondary' && styles.secondary,
  ],
})<MyThemeComponentProps>(({ theme }) => ({
  backgroundColor: 'aliceblue',
  padding: theme.spacing(1),
}));

export default function UsingOptions() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={customTheme}>
      <MyThemeComponent sx={{ m: 1 }} color="primary" variant="dashed">
        Primary
      </MyThemeComponent>
      <MyThemeComponent sx={{ m: 1 }} color="secondary">
        Secondary
      </MyThemeComponent>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: There is no need to add your signature at the end of the post. Its already there below your answer

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting, should be something like this -

```
The types of 'props.variant' are incompatible between these types.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"dashed" | "outlined" | "text" | "contained" | undefined'.
```

It says, `variant` can only accept `'"hoverable" | "outlined" | "text" | "contained" | undefined'`

Try using `props: { variant: "hoverable" as const }` instead of  `props: { variant: "hoverable" }`.

For more detail on this typescript issue check - [Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type)