# Typescript Error on Union type in generic : ' is not assignable to type'

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, casting, union-types

I have an abstract class with a Generic that I implement with a Union type such as :

```
export abstract class DAO<T> { 
  async getDocument(ref: string): Promise<T> {
        // irrelevant code that return T asynchronously
  }
}

export class ConfigurationDAO extends DAO<ConfigurationType> {
 //...
}

export type ConfigurationType = 'advertising' | 'theming';
```

The `getDocument()` signature for the `ConfigurationDAO` class is then :

```
async getDocument(ref: string): Promise<ConfigurationType>
```

The problem is that when I call this function, I have an error :

```
const advertisingDocument: 'advertising' = await this.getDocument('advertising');
```

the error :

```
Type 'ConfigurationType' is not assignable to type '"advertising"'.
  Type '"theming"' is not assignable to type '"advertising"'
```

I don't understand why the `'advertising'` type is not valid when the return type is `'advertising' | 'theming'`

Comment: Explanation of why that doesn't work, as well as possible solutions:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51101237/197472

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I found a solution in that indeed. I finally assigned by typecasting the `getDocument()` function : `const advertisingDocument: 'advertising' = await this.getDocument('advertising') as 'advertising';` Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Typescript automatically types your `advertisingDocument` as `ConfigurationType` and you are trying to force-type it differently.
Think of it as if it was basic types.
For typescript you are basically doing the same as:

```
const test: number = 'name';
```

Being that `'name'` is a string it isn't assignable to `test` which I declared as a `number`.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation ! The answer of @Barryman9000 helped me to found a solution to this