# Number type to custom type of number

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, numbers

I created a simple type:

```
export type CustomType = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5;
```

Now I want to initialize an already declared variable (current value = 0) of this type with the result of

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)
```

Now, TypeScript tells me, that the Type number is not assignable to Type CustomType, even though the initialization should work as long the number is a whole number of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, or 5.:

> TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'CustomType'.

Unfortunately, I failed to find any solution thus far. Casting to standard types is fine, but I am unsure how to make my custom type accept a number.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a type assertion like this:

```
const value = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) as CustomType;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, did not know of the "of" keyword. Will take a look at it immediately.Will also mark as answer as soon as StackOverflow lets me.

Comment: @0kMike don't forget to upvote this answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I did, but this account does not have 15 reputation yet.
Edit: nvm now it has

Comment: @0kMike you already have :D