# Typescript: Type 'string' not assignable to a string of fixed values

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am new to typescript.I am working on a backed that uses Express, Node and Typescript.  I have an object that has type:

```
interface Fruit {
 FruitType: "Citrus" | "Melon" | "Tropical" 
 FruitName: string
}
```

I am creating a new instance of Fruit where I am reding the fruit type from JSON file and populating it

```
const config = readFromFile()
const myFruit:Fruit ={
 FruitName: config.fruitName,
 FruitType: config.fruitTYPE
}
```

This gives an error `Type 'string' not assignable to type "Citrus" | "Melon" | "Tropical"`. I understand I am getting this error because I am assigning an unknown string instead of an Enum value. I am assuming the solution is to somehow check if the fruit type is one of the values before assigning it to the FruitType object. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type)

Comment: Can  source of `readFromFile()` be typed ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [cast it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions).

```
type fruitCategories =  "Citrus" | "Melon" | "Tropical" 
interface Fruit {
 FruitType: fruitCategories
 FruitName: string
}
```

Now, you have the `fruitCategories` that sets the fruitType.

```
const config = readFromFile()
const myFruit:Fruit ={
 FruitName: config.fruitName,
 FruitType: config.fruitTYPE as fruitCategories // you need to tell the complier
}
```

So, you need to cast the type from string and tell the complier that this should be of type `fruitCategories` or anyname you want.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to cast the value and use it.

```
    type fruitType=  "Citrus" | "Melon" | "Tropical"

    interface Fruit {
      FruitType: fruitType
      FruitName: string
    }
    
    const config = readFromFile()
    const myFruit : Fruit = {
      FruitName: config.fruitName,
      FruitType: config.fruitTYPE as fruitType // Cast the config.fruitTYPE to fruitType
    }
```