# ts(2345) Argument of type '...' is not assignable to parameter of type '...'

Tags: typescript

```
type FruitName = 'apple' | 'banana';

interface Fruit {
    name: FruitName;
}

const apple = {
    'name': 'apple',
};

function test(fruit: Fruit) {
    console.log(fruit.name);
}

function main() {
    const name: FruitName = 'apple'; // this is ok

    test(apple); // error TS2345: Argument of type '{ name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Fruit'.type 'FruitName'
                 //   Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
                 //     Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'FruitName'.
}

main();
```

I couldn't figure out why apple is not assignable to Fruit.

But, 'apple' is assignable to name: FruitName.

What's difference of two?

Comment: `apple = { 'name': 'apple' as const }` would work.

Comment: Or declare apple as Fruit. `const apple: Fruit`

Comment: Or `test(apple as Fruit);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`const apple = { 'name': 'apple' as const }` would work.

`"apple"` alone is inferred as `string` type, while `"apple" as const` is inferred as `"apple"` *string literal* type. String literal is subtype of string, not the other way around.

```
let appleString: string = "apple"
let appleLiteral: "apple" = "apple" as const

appleString = appleLiteral // ok
appleLiteral = appleString // error
```