# Type 'string' is not assignable

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Here's how I define and use my type in my react app:

**FontSize.ts**

```
    const fontSize = {
        xs: 'xs',
        sm: 'sm',
        base: 'base',
        lg: 'lg',
        xl: 'xl'
    }
    
    export default Object.freeze(fontSize);
```

And this is my simple Text component:

**Text.tsx**

```
import { FontSize } from '@bl/foundation';

interface TextProps {
   size?: keyof typeof FontSize,
   children: React.ReactNode;
}
const Text:React.FC<TextProps> = ({ size = FontSize.sm, children }) => {
    const  classNames = `font-size-${size}`;
    return <p className={classNames}>
        {children}
    </p>
}
```

when I write my component:

```
<Text size={FontSize.lg} > Some text here. </Text>
```

It show me in the size property this error:

`Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"xs" | "sm" | "lg" | "xl" | "base" | undefined'.`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type)

Comment: Can you show the code of `FontSize`, is it an `enum`?

Comment: @hackape no not the some case

Comment: @belal, please use `Enum` for `FontSize` and no need to use `Object.freeze`

Comment: You can use strings as types without creating a wrapper enum. Example: `type MyType = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';
const x: MyType = 'a'; // Valid
const y: MyType = 'd'; // Invalid`

Comment: @CuongVu Object.freeze was the problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an enum `FontSize` (see below) to replace the `fontSize` object.

Enum:

```
enum FontSize {
    XS = "xs",
    SM = "sm",
    BASE = "base",
    LG = "lg",
    XL = "xl",
}
```

This also allows you to remove the `Object.freeze` function call.

Then change the `TextProps` interface so that `size` is of type `FontSize` (the enum created):

```
interface TextProps {
    size?: FontSize,
    children: React.ReactNode;
}
```