# Type '{ status: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MyType'. Types of property 'status' are incompatible. Type 'string' is not assignable to type

Tags: typescript

I have a .ts file and I want to use the following type definition:

```
type MyType = {
    status: "ACTIVE" | "INACTIVE"
}
```

When I use this type for a variable which I directly set value, everything is good:

```
const myObj1: MyType = {
    status: "ACTIVE"
}
```

But if I use a variable to set the value I get an error:

```
const data = {
    status: "ACTIVE"
}
const myObj2: MyType = data
```

Error:

```
Type '{ status: string; }' is not assignable to type 'MyType'.
  Types of property 'status' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"ACTIVE" | "INACTIVE"'.
```

You can try it on [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQM7AENgBXXALigCIBBAYXgEkA1AUUqgB8qGA5Ox1pQwBfDGIDGAewB2+KAFsQAeQBGAKwCMFOIkhRUmHHkIlyVfszYixGKbOBQAJkQL70WHPiKkKNepaFROzlFVTUAJm0EJDdnQgwgA)

I tried different options (like [this](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type)), but the problem is that my types are generated from Json Schemas and I can't edit the generated files.

Comment: The compiler's telling you the correct thing - without further information, the inferred type of `data` is `{ status: string }` - the object is mutable and a different string could be assigned. You could do e.g. `const data = { status: "ACTIVE" } as const;` or even `const data = { status: "ACTIVE" as const };` to tell the compiler that shouldn't change and get the narrower type `{ status: "ACTIVE" }`, which is compatible with `MyType`. But then you might as well just have `const data: MyType = { ... }`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. 
@jonrsharpe the question and the answers are similar but the problem is not exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `status` in `data` is infered as a `string` whereas `MyType` expects it to be either  `"ACTIVE"` or `"INACTIVE"`.
You need just to use `as const` assertion

```js
type MyType = {
    status: "ACTIVE" | "INACTIVE"
}


const myObj1: MyType = {
    status: "ACTIVE"
}


const data = {
    status: "ACTIVE"
} as const
const myObj2: MyType = data
```

Or you can use new [`satisfies`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-9-beta/#hamilton) keyword which is available in TS 4.9

```js
type MyType = {
    status: "ACTIVE" | "INACTIVE"
}

const myObj1: MyType = {
    status: "ACTIVE"
}

const data = {
    status: "ACTIVE"
} satisfies MyType
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wgln4N)

Comment: Thank you, It works fine. For me the first one is better, because the VS Code does not know the `satisfies` keyword yet.

Comment: Correct: The first one is NOT OK if I use arrays. But if I use `as MyType` instead of `as const` it works well: 
[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.0-dev.20220921#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiAq5oF4oG8BQVtQM7AENgBXXALigCIBBAYXgEkA1AUUqgB8qGA5Ox1pSw4AxgQBO5PMHEBLAHYBzANoBdDAF8MGAPQ6A8gGkMIgPbz8UALYh9AIwBWFOIkhRUmHNKKkKNesxsADTC2GKSFMqUAEIEFgAWEBCUQVS0iRCE8ZTqWroGxmYWwFAAJkQEAIzu6KHeJFL+AsF14VJRsQlJKWkZWTmaeESyuABmshC4sAhIJuaWNvYOlc4zbqjlhJXaeiwASnv6e3PFZRUATDWeOPg+jfyBKa0S7TFxuBk9lOlJ-blQBCmRXwJwWtkc51WrhQZ0I5x2BVBJU2BAAzFc6rcGn4HoIQl42pE3l1kqlvn0CNl-oDptCkdZwQ5UVCkDUUaiMEA).

Comment: Please keep in mind that using `as MyType` in your last example is not safe. See [this](https://tsplay.dev/mx3PXN)