# Angular 14 pathMatch Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"full" | "prefix"' Error

Tags: angular14

Just upgraded to Angular 14, getting error:

```
Types of property 'pathMatch' are incompatible.
        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"full" | "prefix"'.
```

Calling from:

```
import { Routes as routes } from './routes';
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
    ]...})
```

with routes being

```
export const Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/signup',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }]
```

The whole thing worked perfectly on Angular 10. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can create a type and cast to it:

```
type PathMatch = "full" | "prefix" | undefined;

const routes = [
  {
    path: 'achievements',
    component: AchievementOverviewComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full' as PathMatch
  }
]
```

More info in a related answer: [Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type/37978675#37978675).

Comment: Do you have any idea why this is ? In the link, they talk about how to solve the specific problem, but they don"t give a hint to why that genereal phenomenon appears. In this case, I would think that "full" would be one of the explicit possibilities as it is a specific string. (pathMatch being derived from Type string). Also, why did it work in previous angular versions ?

Comment: @paulrusu It's to do with TypeScript, not angular in itself. You'd be better off asking this as a separate question or as a comment on the answer I linked to. There are many who are much better suited to answer you.

Answer (score 11):

Just define routes as `Routes`, so TypeScript will know that `pathMatch` is `'full'`, `'prefix'` or `undefined`.

This is better than the currently accepted (and working) answer, because it also type checks the other properties.

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/signup',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }]
```

Comment: Huh, this is much better than the accepted one.