# Type 'string' is not assignable to type - How to type an object in array?

Tags: typescript

I have a long array:

```js
const allRoles = {
   'product_manager': [
      {
         id: 'productManager_1',
         image: '/icon.png',
         title: 'CEO of the product',
         description: 'Some description'.</>,
      },
   'backend_engineer': [{...}]
   ...
}
```

Component code:

```js
// roleTitle = "Product Manager"
export function OverviewModal(roleTitle: string) {

  const convertedRole: keyof typeof allRoles = roleTitle.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'_');
  const roleCardInfo = allRoles[convertedRole];
  // Tried the above but got an error:
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"product_manager" | "backend_engineer"...'.ts(2322)
```

In this case, this doesn't seem to apply:
[Typescript Type 'string' is not assignable to type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978528/typescript-type-string-is-not-assignable-to-type)

Instead of a class, I just have an object of arrays. I'm not sure what type it would be in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cengen is right.

But, may you would have a solution to your problem if you were able to know at compile time the key of AllRoles like this :

```
const roleTypeNames = ['product_manager','backend_engineer'] as const;
type roleType = typeof roleTypeNames[number]

const allRoles : {[key in roleType]:any} = { ... };
```

if yes, then you can use a typeguard.

```
const isRoleType = (candidate : string) : candidate is roleType => {
    for(const role of roleTypeNames)
    {
        if(role === candidate) return true  ;
    }
    return false;
}

 function OverviewModal(roleTitle: string) {
    const sanitizedRoleTitle = roleTitle.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'_');
    if(isRoleType(sanitizedRoleTitle))
    {  
        const roleCardInfo = allRoles[sanitizedRoleTitle];
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

So at this part you are literally saying that `convertedRole` should be some key of `allRoles`.

```
const convertedRole: keyof typeof allRoles
```

the type of `allRoles` is the shape of the value you are giving it. And you have declared your argument `roleTitle` as a string. So a string is not narrow enough a type for convertedRole. convertedRole can only be assigned strings that are equal to the keys of the type of `allRoles`, aka the strings "product_manager" | "backend_engineer"...'.

Remember that typescript does not exist in runtime. It can not know the actual value of roleTitle as you run the code.